# maximum_spanning_tree networkx has no attribute

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx, graph-visualization

I am trying to find maximum spanning tree of a network using networkx python module.
According to documentation specified[link below], nx.maximum_spanning_tree(G) should do this work. But i am getting error

```
  File "air_traffic_network_base.py", line 65, in <module>
    max_spanning_tree = nx.maximum_spanning_tree(net)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'maximum_spanning_tree'
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
net = nx.read_weighted_edgelist(graph_file)
min_spanning_tree = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(net) #no error
max_spanning_tree = nx.maximum_spanning_tree(net) #error here
```

Documentation:
http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.tree.mst.maximum_spanning_tree.html

```
Networkx version (nx.__version__):
1.10
```

I believe i am using latest networkx python module.(minimum_spanning_tree function call works without any error).

Please help.

Comment: I think the maximum_spanning_tree function is in version 2.0 try to install it and give it another shot

Comment: Looks like the version 1.10 doesn't have all the functions specified in the documentation. Most of them are present in development release (not stable release 1.10). For more information check http://networkx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html for installing development release from git.

Comment: I found a better way to do this in version 1.1
Change all the edge weights to negative (-1 * edge_weight) and take MST. This gives the maximum spanning tree.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is due to your net being directed. If that is the case, maximum_spanning_tree will not work. Since as the documentation reports, it can only be done on an undirected graph.

The models that can be represented by the two are equivalent, and so it's just a change to the way you represent the model with factors. To make a directed tree from an undirected one, just pick any node as the root and orient the edges away from the root.