# Updating to networkx 2.0 in conda?

Tags: python-2.7, networkx, conda

I need to use [maximum_spanning_tree](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.tree.mst.maximum_spanning_tree.html) in my Python Notebook (Jupiter). Can someone tell me how I can update my networkx to 2.+ in conda?

I read the documentation at http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html but it only updates to 1.11. It seems I need to install the development version.

It looks like maximum_spanning_tree is not supported by networkx 1.11.

Sidenote: For networkx 1.1, one user suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33962090/maximum-spanning-tree-networkx-has-no-attribute) to change all the edge weights to negative (-1 * edge_weight) and take MST (Minimum Spanning Tree?). The user claims this would return the maximum spanning tree. Any conformation?

Thanks!

**Solved** via console:

```
git clone https://github.com/networkx/networkx.git

cd networkx

python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to install the current master branch using:

```
$ pip install git+http://github.com/networkx/networkx
```

The master branch should be in good shape and we would love additional feedback on it as we finalize the 2.0 release.

Comment: NetworkX 2.0 was released on Sept. 20th.  It is now available on PyPI (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/networkx/).  The documentation is here:  https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/

Comment: Nice!  I have the old version installed via conda.  Is there a conda channel you recommend to update via conda?

Comment: I've never used conda, but it looks like conda-forge has updated to 2.0:  https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/networkx